# Is there a way to log the select query instead of all general queries in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have enabled the General log to monitor retrieve queries. But it gave me all the queries(like insert,update and delete). So I have to run the cron job to fetch select queries in general log. This procedure is more likely the following steps.

- Mysql writes the general log
- I am running the job for every 3 hours which will get the select query from the general log and write it in another file, finally clear the general log.

So what I need is only select queries want to be logged instead of all queries. Is there any way to achieve it? Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any built in option present for this. You will have to continue doing the process you have currently.